# Approximating high-energy Compton scattering cross section

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering-cross-section

I’m trying to obtain the approximation (5.94) on page 164 of Peskin and Schroeder’s “Introduction to QFT”.

Let an electron with momentum $p = (E,-\omega\hat z)$ scatter off a photon with momentum $k = (\omega, \omega \hat z)$ in the center of mass frame. Then, for $E\gg m$ and $\theta\approx \pi$, the differential cross section is approximately:

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{d\sigma}{d\cos\theta} &\approx \frac 12\cdot\frac 1{2E}\cdot \frac 1{2\omega} \frac {\omega}{(2\pi)4(E + \omega)}\cdot\frac{2 e^4 (E+\omega)}{E+\omega\cos\theta}.\end{aligned}\tag{5.94a}$$

The RHS equals

$$\frac{1}{16(2\pi)E}\cdot\frac{4\pi}{4\pi}\cdot\frac{e^4}{E+\omega\cos\theta}=\frac{4\pi}{8E}\cdot\frac{e^4}{(4\pi)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{E+\omega\cos\theta}=\frac{2\pi\alpha^2}{4E(E+\cos\theta)}.$$

How can this be further approximated to

$$\frac{2\pi\alpha^2}{2m^2+s(1+\cos\theta)},\tag{5.94b}$$

where $s = (k+p)^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation}
\frac{d\sigma}{d\cos\theta}  = \frac{\alpha^2\pi}{2}  \frac{1}{E(E+\omega\cos\theta)}
\end{equation}
Look at the denominator. Start by writing $E(E+\omega \cos\theta) = E\omega(E/\omega + \cos\theta)$. Next, from $m^2=E^2-\omega^2$ find $E/\omega =\sqrt{1+m^2/\omega^2} \approx 1+m^2/2\omega^2$. Therefore
\begin{align}
E(E+\omega \cos\theta) =& E\omega \left(1+\frac{m^2}{2\omega^2} +\cos\theta\right) = E\omega(1+\cos\theta) +\frac{Em^2}{2\omega}
\end{align}
Now $s=(p+k)^2 = 2p\cdot k = 2 E(E+\omega)$ and in the high energy regime $0\approx m^2 = E^2-\omega^2$ and therefore $E\approx \omega$ and so $s/2= E(E+\omega) = 2E\omega$ and $E/\omega \approx 1$. We therefore find
\begin{align}
E(E+\omega \cos\theta) =& \frac{1}{4} s (1+\cos\theta)+ \frac{1}{2}m^2
\end{align}
which gives the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

- I want to share a little more, because I also meet puzzles when I approximated it: $E\approx\omega\gg m$, $s=2p\cdot k=2\omega(E+\omega)+m^2$ so that $E\omega \approx \omega^2\approx s/4$, plugging them into the denominator of cross section,
  $$E(E+\omega\cos{\theta}) = m^2+\omega^2+E\omega\cos{\theta}\approx m^2+\frac{1}{4}s(1+\cos{\theta})$$
  but it's wrong since the formula $\omega^2\approx s/4$ discard the term of $m^2$ order which we need in the final expression.
- let's first find the transformation between $(E,\omega)$ and $(s,m)$
  $$
  \begin{cases}
  s =m^2 + 2\omega(E+\omega)\\
  m^2 = E^2 - \omega^2 
  \end{cases}\Longrightarrow
  \begin{cases}
  E = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sqrt{s} + \frac{m^2}{\sqrt{s}} \right)\\
  \omega = \frac{1}{2} \left( \sqrt{s} - \frac{m^2}{\sqrt{s}} \right)
  \end{cases}
  $$
  then the denominator becomes
  $$
  \begin{align}
  E(E+\omega\cos{\theta}) 
  &= \frac{1}{4}\left(s+2m^2+\frac{m^4}{s}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\left( s-\frac{m^4}{s} \right)\cos{\theta} 
  \\
  &= \frac{1}{2}m^2+\frac{1}{4}s(1+\cos{\theta}) + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{m^4}{s}\right)
  \end{align}
  $$
  maybe this process would be more clear since we only make approxiamtion in the final step.
- In a word, be careful about the error when we make approximations.